# cvNorm() always returns 0 when comparing webcam frames

Tags: c++, c, opencv, webcam

I'm trying to write a program that prints out the norm between two frames (30 frames apart) captured from a webcam, but cvNorm always returns 0. What am I doing wrong? Code follows:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
CvCapture *capture = 0;
IplImage  *frame = 0;
int       key = 0;

/* initialize camera */ 
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

/* always check */
if ( !capture ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
    return 1;
}


/* create a window for the video */
cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

IplImage *image;
IplImage pastImage;

for(int i = 0; key != 'q'; i++ ) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Here's where the checking occurs:

```
if(!(i %30)){
        if(i){
            cout<<cvNorm(&pastImage,image)<<endl;
        }
        memcpy(&pastImage,image, sizeof(IplImage));
    }


    frame = image;              

    /* always check */
    if( !frame ) break;

    /* display current frame */ 
    cvShowImage( "result", frame );
    /* exit if user press 'q' */
    key = cvWaitKey( 1 );
}

/* free memory */
cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcpy'ing the image object does not copy the image. It copies the image metadata. The metadata points to the actual image pixels. There should be an image copy function in OpenCV. Call that.

Here's a tutorial on the subject: http://nashruddin.com/opencv-examples-for-operation-on-images.html/4

Comment: the link does not work. It rather loads some random page to clean the OS.